# Python reading text from file not finding apostrophes

Tags: python, text, encoding, nlp, readfile

A function for cleaning a text

```
def clean_before_tok(text):
    text=text.replace("'"," ")
    exclude=[" le "," la "," l "," un "," une "," du "," de "," les "," des "," s "," d "]
    for e in exclude:
        text=text.replace(e," ")
    return text
```

I can test this on a pet example

```
test=clean_before_tok("dlkj dfg le se d'ac")
print(test)
>>> dlkj dfg se ac
```

But when reading from file with

```
generated_text=open("text-like.txt", 'rb').read().decode(encoding='utf-8')
```

It's not finding-replacing apostrophes. Is there an encoding flaws?

Comment: have you tried reading it without the binary flag ?

Comment: Can you give an example of the apostrophes in your file? Are you sure they are "'" and not "`"?

Comment: @olirwin looks very bad

Comment: @IainShelvington I tried all the apostrophes

Comment: To be explicit, `open("text-like.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()` is the idiomatic and succinct way to read UTF-8 text from a file.

Comment: @tripleee thanks, this is not solving it unfortunately

Comment: Try apostrophe-like symbols e.g. `‘` (U+2018,  *Left Single Quotation Mark*),  `’` (U+2019,  *Right Single Quotation Mark*) or `‛` (U+201B,  *Single High-Reversed-9 Quotation Mark*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to check the encoding of the file, you may print it as bytes

```py
>>> with open("my-file.txt", "rb") as file:
...     b_file = file.read()
>>> print(b_file)
```

If the apostrophes shows like apostrophes it's very weird. Normally the issue will be explained by the presence of weird `\xAB` (`AB` can be any letters uppercase or lowercase, they represent a non-ASCII byte) in your text.

Comment: If the assumption is that the file contains UTF-8, there is no sane reason to read it as binary. You complicate your code, and lose the warning at read time if something is not actually valid UTF-8.

Comment: very good answer actually, I could find I had missed `’` U+2019